# Python Connection to database without pyodbc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I'm quite new to Python (using Python 3.6.5) and I need to create a connection to a database, and I do it in Access with the ODBC Driver (I guess?), but for some reasons I just can't install pyodbc here, so I need to do this connection without it. Is there a way to do it?

I'm sorry if there's not much details about it, but I can try to check anything if needed.

Edit - I don't think it's the point here to solve the fact that I can't get the use pip to install, since I know why it isn't working, but here is the print from the log of pip:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what happens when you try `pip install --user pyodbc`.

Comment: Believe me when I say you *do not* want to try to write your own database client software. Use something already existing. The problem appears to be that pip can't reach the server. Check with your IT if it's okay for you to download it from PyPI manually and install it from the file.

Comment: I agree with you, I really wouldn't like to do this but... It's going to take too much time to get that module on my computer, so I guess I'll _have_ to do it this way. Is it too complex/hard...?

Comment: Can you download "pyodbc-4.0.24-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl" from [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/#files)? If so, then you could do `pip install --user  pyodbc-4.0.24-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't download nor install it using pip... The ideia is to do sort of a workaround until I'm able to download it and install it, actually.